# Pivot/Matrix Type custom page in VF/APEX

Tags: apex, visualforce, loop

I have Account object and a custom child object pprevenues__c.
Every month the revenue for Account is captured. I have created a page that would pull the data into a SOQL.

```
select id,name,owner.name,(select revenue__c,version__c,New_customers__c,Customers__c,Account_Product__r.name from pprevenues__r where as_of_date__c>=:cur_date) from account where status__c = 'Active' order by name
```

Version__c is a picklist with three values below

- '>V-2
- V-2
- V-1/V-2

I would like to get a Table like below.

[image]

So far i can get the data into a List . Is it possible to loop through this List and calculate summaries by myself? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: at vf page level you want to calculate summaries ? or you want in apex controller?

Comment: apex controller please

Comment: You can use aggregate query on pprevenues__c and create a wrapper class to store all the values with Account Name.. And show in vf page.. this is the idea I suggest first try yourself first and let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ratan. Below is the sample i have written to get the data out the way i want it.
VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperexample1">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstWrapperString}" var="var">
                <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="A/C Name">
                    {!var.accname}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="A/C Industry">
                    {!var.accindy}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Contact Name">
                    {!var.conname}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Contact Email">
                    {!var.conmail}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Contact A/C Name">
                    {!var.acnname}
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex Class

```
public class wrapperexample1 {
List <wrapper> wrp = new List<wrapper>();
public List <wrapper> getlstWrapperString() {
    List <Account> acccon = [select name,industry,(select name,email,account.name from contacts order by name) from account order by name];
    for(Account acc:acccon) {
        for(Contact con:acc.contacts) {
            wrp.add(new wrapper(acc.name,acc.industry,con.name,con.email,con.account.name));
        }
    }
    return wrp;
}
public class wrapper {
    public string accname {get; set;}
    public string accindy {get; set;}
    public string conname {get; set;}
    public string conmail {get; set;}
    public string acnname {get; set;}
    public wrapper(string accname, string accindy, string conname, string conmail, string acnname) {
        this.accname = accname;
        this.accindy = accindy;
        this.conname = conname;
        this.conmail = conmail;
        this.acnname = acnname;
    }
}
```

}